# Knockoutjs track changes after ajax call

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, kolite

See JsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/WtgbV/2/

In words: I have some ajax call, and in the server's response I get some array of items (Items in knockout viewmodel)

I need to know that property `name` was changed in element with `id==2` etc to save changes automatically on server (via POST request)

What is the simplest/easiest way to track changes in each element in `Items` array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I co-wrote a component called DirtyFlag that detects changes in Knockout observables (or a set of them). You can grab in from my library called KoLite that you can grab off NuGet or GitHub.

https://github.com/CodeSeven/KoLite

https://nuget.org/packages/KoLite

**dirtyFlag**

```
// Your model
var Person = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable();
    self.firstName = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
    self.lastName = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
    self.dirtyFlag = new ko.DirtyFlag([self.firstName,self.lastName]);
    return self;
};
```

Hook these into your viewmodel to detect if there were changes ...

```
//Property on your view model. myPerson is an instance of Person.
//Did it Change?
isDirty = ko.computed(function () {
    return myPerson().dirtyFlag().isDirty();
}),
```

Then to resync the changes ...

```
//Resync Changes
dirtyFlag().reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Knockout has a built in PubSub system (used by their observables and other core elements).

You could make use of this system by extending each of your properties to publish an event on a certain topic after being edited.

You'd then need to have a subscription on this topic so you can track changes in the data.

Take a look at [this excellent post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html)

You can easily achieve this by providing your own mapping. The following is a very basic example, just to show you what the PubSub system could do for you. [See example](http://jsfiddle.net/WtgbV/6/).

If I may give you a hint, it's might be a better idea to not save per property but to detect changes and do an autosave of the whole array after a certain period.

So each value will publish a 'change event' on the topic and each time you receive a message on a topic the timeOut will be reset. After timeout expires you can save changes in the BE.